# Conditional assembly reference via NuGet

Tags: nuget, conditional-compilation, assembly-references, nuget-spec

I have a Visual Studio solution ([TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/)) with a complex set of assembly references and I am looking to solve it using NuGet. The reference depends on target Configuration, not on .Net platform.

**Problem definition**

The Solution has a number of Projects, most of them referencing a common set of assemblies. There are different assemblies' versions exposing API changes. Source code contains scattered [conditional compiles #ifs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to manage the differences in versions. Therefore the projects and the solution have a number of Configurations; Project References change depending on Configuration.

**Current state**

Every project imports a common MSBuild file doing some magic using 
[Choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164307.aspx), as you can see in [the source](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/blob/master/References/TfsReferences.target).
Reference assemblies must reside on a common folder at the Solution level, each version in a different sub-folder.

For example, the source code contains

```
#if TFS2015 || TFS2015u1
using ILocationService = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Server.ILocationService;
#elif TFS2013
using ILocationService = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationLocationService;
#else
#error Define TFS version!
#endif
```

The solution has a `Debug-2013` Configuration defining the `TFS2013` compile symbol and importing the MSBuild snippet

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)References\2013\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

pointing to the correct assembly version.
A similar `Debug-2015` Configuration defines the `TFS2015` compile symbol and imports

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)References\2015\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**The downside of current state**

The downside of this solution is managing the Reference folder. On every new client machine I need to copy the correct files, ditto for build server.
I would like to use NuGet to manage this mess.

**NuGet attempt #1**

I tried this in the `.nuspec` file

```
<files>
    <file src=".\References\TfsReferences.target" target="content\References\TfsReferences.target" />
    <file src=".\References\2013\*.dll" target="content\References\2013" />
    <file src=".\References\2015\*.dll" target="content\References\2015" />
    <file src=".\References\2015.1\*.dll" target="content\References\2015.1" />
    <file src=".\References\2015.2\*.dll" target="content\References\2015.2" />
</files>
```

but it ends creating a Reference folder on each project and does not solve the conditional references.

Comment: I would take a look at creating a NuGet package that has a [custom MSBuild .targets file](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#import-msbuild-targets-and-props-files-into-project) with all your conditional references defined in there.